# Computer freezes during POST with new CD drive

Tags: boot, bios, freeze, optical-drive, cd

I work with older computers and received a Compaq Presario 2275 with a non-working CD drive. After cleaning up the computer and testing it (it works fine), I swapped the original 32x CD drive with a tested and working 52x CD drive from a different computer.

After connecting the cables to the drive (and confirming they were properly installed), along with configuring the jumper, the computer hangs on the “Compaq” logo screen. Hitting escape after powering on runs a self test, which hangs immediately after recognizing the CD drive. I can’t enter the BIOS, as it must first complete this test. Just as a note, the PC does also boot with no CD drive installed.

What could be causing the computer to hang only with the new drive, even after it is recognized by the BIOS?

Comment: Is the jumper set to CS?

Comment: @Moab, the jumper is set to CS. That's exactly what the older 32x drive that came with the computer was set to.

Comment: Since you are using CS, I suspect it's an IDE drive. If so does it share IDE cable with another device? If so, try putting the drive on separate cable and separate IDE slot if available and check again. If not possible, disconnect HDD and keep only CD Drive for the time being and test again if it clears POST.

Comment: @patkim, yes, it is an IDE drive. It’s sharing a cable with the computer’s hard drive, which is the same as the original configuration with the old CD drive. I disconnected the hard drive and left the CD drive plugged in, and sure enough the system made it past POST. What does this mean? Should I change the jumpers to master/slave instead of cable select?

Comment: @jacobtohahn Yes try both CS  and setting jumper to correct M or S setting as applicable. Also try keeping HDD & CD Drive both as Master on two separate cables if possible, if you have 2 IDE slots. Also check if with just HDD it clears POST or not, in case indeed it's hanging at HDD detection or something. Try out these combinations and see if any one works.